# Raycasting python (pyagame)

Tags: python, pygame, raycasting

I want to share my raycasting source (the first engine:)

this program renders the game map (MAP array) and sprites (sprites_on_map array)

ask and criticize!

p.s I don't speak/write English very well (not my native language), but I tried to make the comments clear

[image]  This is data/wall_1.bmp

[image]  This is data/sprite_1.bmp

```
import pygame as p
import math   as m

FOV, FOV_STEP, LENGHT_STEP, MAX_LENGHT = 1., .00375, .01, 50.
prespeed   = .08  # explained in the wall_render method
rotate     = .1
pspeed     = .25

FPS = 30

WID, HEI = 320, 200
win = p.display.set_mode((WID, HEI), p.FULLSCREEN)
win.set_alpha(None)
p.event.set_allowed([])

dWID            = 261  # game window width
dHEI            = 161  # game window height
dWIDs           = (WID - dWID) // 2  # game window start draw x
dHEIs           = 10  # game window start draw y
mulHEI          = 1.5 # wall size y
mulSPR_HEI      = 1
sprite_max_size = 1000

FOV_STEP = FOV / (dWID + 1)

win.fill((50, 50, 50))

walls = {1 : 'data/wall_1.bmp'}

sprites = {1 : 'data/sprite_1.bmp'}
              # if this is a multi-sided sprite : list of keys to image paths
              # example:
              # 1 : 'data/side1.bmp'
              # 2 : 'data/side2.bmp'
              # 3 : [1, 2]
              # 3 is a multi-side sprite

animated_sprites = {}  # key :
                       # [ frames ([sprite key1, sprite key2, ...]),
                       # loop (True/False),
                       # frame ( > 0, < len(frames)),
                       # speed (now_image = frames[int(frame + speed)])]

solid_sprites = [1]

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- LEVEL
px, py, pa = 1.5, 2.5, 6.28  # player x + .5 , player y + .5 , player angle
sprites_on_map = {0 : [2.5, 2.5, 1]}  # key : [x + .5, y + .5, key to sprite, if this is a multi-sided sprite : degree (radians)

MAP = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]  # keys from walls

roof_color, floor_color = (56, 56, 56), (112, 112, 112)  # (R, G, B), (R, G, B)

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- END LEVEL

redraw = True

p.mouse.set_visible(False)
p.mouse.set_pos((dWIDs + dWID // 2, dHEIs + dHEI // 2))
mouse_speed = .001



def moving(x, y, ang):
    ystep = y + m.sin(ang) * pspeed
    xstep = x + m.cos(ang) * pspeed
    if MAP[int(ystep)][int(xstep)] == 0:
        for i in sprites_on_map.keys():
            sprite = sprites_on_map.get(i)
            if sprite[2] in solid_sprites:
                if int(sprite[0]) == int(xstep) and int(sprite[1]) == int(ystep):
                    return
        return y + m.sin(ang) * pspeed, x + m.cos(ang) * pspeed



def wall_render(x, y, ang):
    screen = []  # fow drawing
    angle  = ang - FOV / 2  # start of scan
    while angle < pa + FOV / 2:

        # the method of recalculating the beam (I've never heard of this, I thought of it myself :)

        # the idea is that the beam goes at a speed of N and as soon as it collides
        # with the wall goes 1 N back and continues to go at a speed of M (M < N) so you can get more quality

        # so prespeed is N and LENGHT_STEP is M

        Cang  = m.cos(angle)
        Sang  = m.sin(angle)

        rstep = prespeed  # speed of ray (now N)
        rfar  = 0         # far of ray

        obj   = 0

        while rfar < MAX_LENGHT:
            rfar += rstep

            rayy  = y + Sang * rfar
            rayx  = x + Cang * rfar

            obj   = MAP[int(rayy)][int(rayx)]

            if obj != 0:  # if ray in wall then speed of ray is M
                if rstep == prespeed:
                    rfar -= rstep
                    rstep = LENGHT_STEP
                    obj   = 0
                else:
                    break

        if obj != 0:
            xside = False
            if MAP[int(rayy)][int(rayx - Cang * rstep)] ==\
               MAP[int(rayy)][int(rayx + Cang * rstep)]:
                # if the left side of the beam and the right side are the same wall, then this is the "x" side of the wall
                xside = True

            if xside:
                # cut is the percentage for getting a slice of the wall (drawing a strip of wall)
                if py > rayy : cut = 1 - rayx + int(rayx)  # fix mirroring of the wall image
                else :         cut = rayx - int(rayx)

            else:
                if px < rayx : cut = 1 - rayy + int(rayy)  # fix mirroring of the wall image
                else :         cut = rayy - int(rayy)

            screen.append(['wall', rfar, angle - ang, obj, cut, xside])  # screen[0] is the type of object (2 types: wall/sprite)
                                                                         # screen[1] is far to wall
                                                                         # screen[2] is object (for draw) of wall
                                                                         # screen[3] is cut
                                                                         # screen[4] is side (for drawing the dark side of the wall)

        angle += FOV_STEP

    return screen



def sprite_render(sprites_on_map, drawed, x, y, ang):
    screen = []
    for i in sprites_on_map.keys():

        sprite      = sprites_on_map.get(i)

        sprite_dist = m.sqrt((x - sprite[0]) * (x - sprite[0]) +
                             (y - sprite[1]) * (y - sprite[1]))  # Pythagorean theorem

        sprite_dir  = m.atan2(sprite[1] - py, sprite[0] - px) - ang  #  you will need it to calculate the beginning of drawing by x

        while sprite_dir < -3.14 : sprite_dir += 6.28
        while sprite_dir >  3.14 : sprite_dir -= 6.28

        sprite_size = min(sprite_max_size, dHEI / sprite_dist * mulHEI)

        horizontal  = (sprite_dir + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP - sprite_size * dWID / dHEI / 2 + dWIDs  # beginning of drawing by x

        if horizontal + sprite_size * dWID / dHEI > dWIDs and horizontal < dWID + dWIDs:

            start_scan = int(horizontal) - dWIDs                             if horizontal > dWIDs                                    else 0     # sprite_draw_x_start
            end_scan   = int(horizontal + sprite_size * dWID / dHEI) - dWIDs if horizontal + sprite_size * dWID / dHEI < dWID + dWIDs else dWID  # sprite_draw_x_end

            #  if the sprite is behind the wall, it is not visible, so you do not need to draw it, and this is calculated in the next "for"

            can_add_sprite = False
            for xx in drawed[start_scan:end_scan]:
                if xx[0] == 'wall':
                    if xx[1] > sprite_dist:  # if we can see this sprite : we draw it
                        can_add_sprite = True
                        break

            if can_add_sprite:
                vertical   = dHEIs + (dHEI - sprite_size * mulSPR_HEI) / 2  # y position on screen of the sprite
                obj        = sprite[2]

                if i in animated_sprites:
                    obj = animated_sprites.get(i)[0][int(animated_sprites.get(i)[2])]

                if type(sprites.get(obj)) is list:  # multi-sided sprites
                    degree = sprites_on_map.get(i)[3] - pa + .3925

                    while degree < 0     : degree += 6.28
                    while degree > 6.28  : degree -= 6.28

                    obj = sprites.get(obj)[int(degree / (6.28 / len(sprites.get(obj))))]

                screen.append(['sprite', sprite_dist, horizontal, vertical, obj, sprite_size])  # screen[0] is the type of object (2 types: wall/sprite)
                                                                                                # screen[1] is the distantion to the sprite
                                                                                                # screen[2] is the x position on screen of the sprite
                                                                                                # screen[3] is the y position on screen of the sprite
                                                                                                # screen[4] is the size of the sprite

    return screen



def rescreen(screen):
    # (255, 0, 255) is the None color
    win.set_alpha(None)  # I've heard it makes the game faster)
    old_path = None

    for i in screen:
        if i[0] == 'wall':
            i.pop(0)
            height = dHEI / (i[0] * m.cos(i[1])) * mulHEI

            start_draw = 0      if height > dHEI else int(dHEI - height) // 2
            start_cut  = 0      if height < dHEI else (height - dHEI) / 2
            end_cut    = height if height < dHEI else dHEI

            if old_path != walls.get(i[2]):
                nimg     = p.image.load(walls.get(i[2]))
                old_path = walls.get(i[2])

            img = p.transform.scale(nimg, (nimg.get_size()[0], int(height)))

            if i[4]:  # dark wall side
                img.set_alpha(100)

                p.draw.line(win,
                            (0, 0, 0),
                            (int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, start_draw + dHEIs),
                            (int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, start_draw + dHEIs + end_cut))

            if start_draw != 0:  # roof
                p.draw.line(win,
                            roof_color,
                            (int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, dHEIs),
                            (int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, dHEIs + start_draw))

            if end_cut != dHEI:  # floor
                p.draw.line(win,
                            floor_color,
                            (int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, dHEIs + dHEI),
                            (int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, dHEIs + end_cut + start_draw))

            win.blit(img,  # wall
                     img.get_rect(topleft=(int((i[1] + FOV / 2) / FOV_STEP) + dWIDs, start_draw + dHEIs)),
                     (nimg.get_size()[0] * i[3], start_cut, 1, end_cut + 1))

        elif i[0] == 'sprite':
            i.pop(0)

            img = p.image.load(sprites.get(i[3]))
            img.set_colorkey((255, 0, 255))

            img = p.transform.scale(img, (int(i[4] * dWID / dHEI), int(i[4] * mulSPR_HEI)))

            # all these calculations are necessary so that the sprite does not go beyond the screen

            start_draw_x = dWIDs if i[1] < dWIDs else int(i[1])
            start_draw_y = dHEIs if i[2] < dHEIs else int(i[2])

            cut_xs = 0 if i[1] > dWIDs else dWIDs - i[1]
            cut_ys = 0 if i[2] > dHEIs else dHEIs - i[2]

            cut_xe = int(i[4] * dWID / dHEI) if start_draw_x + int(i[4] * dWID / dHEI) < dWID + dWIDs else dWIDs + dWID - start_draw_x + 1
            cut_ye = int(i[4] * mulSPR_HEI)  if start_draw_y + i[4] < dHEIs + dHEI                    else dHEIs + dHEI - start_draw_y

            win.blit(img,  # sprite draw
                     img.get_rect(topleft=(start_draw_x, start_draw_y)),
                     (cut_xs, cut_ys, cut_xe, cut_ye + 1))


    p.display.update()



screen = wall_render(px, py, pa)

while True:

    for e in p.event.get():
        if e == p.QUIT:
            break

    p.time.delay(1000 // FPS)  # wait

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_ESCAPE]:
        break

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_LEFT]:
        pa -= rotate
        if pa < 3.14: pa = 9.42
        redraw = True

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_RIGHT]:
        pa += rotate
        if pa > 9.42: pa = 3.14
        redraw = True

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_UP] or p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_w]:
        res = moving(px, py, pa)
        if res is not None:
            py, px = res
            redraw = True

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_DOWN] or p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_s]:
        res = moving(px, py, pa - 3.14)
        if res is not None:
            py, px = res
            redraw = True

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_a]:
        res = moving(px, py, pa - 1.57)
        if res is not None:
            py, px = res
            redraw = True

    if p.key.get_pressed()[p.K_d]:
        res = moving(px, py, pa + 1.57)
        if res is not None:
            py, px = res
            redraw = True

    if p.mouse.get_pos() != (dWIDs + dWID // 2, dHEIs + dHEI // 2):  # mouse looking
        pa -= (dWIDs + dWID // 2 - p.mouse.get_pos()[0]) * mouse_speed
        if pa < 3.14: pa = 9.42
        if pa > 9.42: pa = 3.14
        redraw = True
        p.mouse.set_pos((dWIDs + dWID // 2, dHEIs + dHEI // 2))

    if animated_sprites != {}:

        fdel = []  # to delete an animation

        for i in animated_sprites.keys():
            sprite = animated_sprites.get(i)
            sprite[2] += sprite[3]
            if int(sprite[2]) >= len(sprite[0]):
                if sprite[1]:
                    animated_sprites.get(i)[2] = 0
                else:
                    sprite[2] -= sprite[3]
                    fdel.append(i)
            else:
                animated_sprites.get(i)[2] = sprite[2]

            if not redraw:
                # should we redraw everything?
                if int(sprite[2] - sprite[3]) != int(sprite[2]) or sprite[2] == 0:
                    if sprite_render({i:sprites_on_map.get(i)},wall_render(px, py, pa),px,py,pa) != []:
                        # yes, hell, we should
                        redraw = True

        for i in fdel:  # delete animations
            del animated_sprites[i]

    if redraw:

        redraw = False

        screen  = wall_render(px, py, pa)                            # wall rendering
        screen += sprite_render(sprites_on_map, screen, px, py, pa)  # sprite rendering

        # the painter's algorithm
        screen.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
        screen = screen[::-1]

        rescreen(screen)  # redraw
```

Comment: Hey Koliqa, whilst I appreciate the effort that went into the comments, could you please [edit] your question to add a short description on what you're raycasting. For example is it a cube or another basic shape, or is it more complex like a scene or a game? Once you've added this information please ping me and I'll help clean up your description :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz , I've re-released everything and made changes to the code (mostly in terms of comments), I'm still open to questions and criticism:) P.S I forgot to clarify: this is a rendering of the game